# Выделяется ли запятыми "по Вашему поручению"?

Tags: пунктуация

Уважаемый Иван Иванович!

Обращение администрации ООО "Заяц" главе города Иркутска
П.П.Иванову по Вашему поручению рассмотрено муниципальным учреждением «Рога и копыта».

Comment: Корректно: обращение К главе города

Answer (score 1):

Сочетание "по вашему поручению" не обособляется, так как является обстоятельством в простом предложении. Оно не имеет значения уточнения и не является вводным словом.